# What is wrong with this meteor syntax?

Tags: syntax, meteor

Im getting an uncaught syntax error on this section.. but I cant for the life of me figure out what could be wrong.. probably hilariously simple but anyways.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  Template.addItem.helpers({
    var equip = function () {
      return Equipment.find().fetch().map(function(it){
        return {name: it.itemName, id: it._id};
      });
    };

     eqp:function(){
      return equip();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Syntax error on which line? What does the error say specifically?

Comment: .helpers() expects one argument, an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put equip function outside helpers

```
var equip = function () {
  return Equipment.find().fetch().map(function(it){
    return {name: it.itemName, id: it._id};
  });
};

Template.addItem.helpers({
     eqp:function(){
      return equip();
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can also have `eqp: equip` instead of `function... equip`. This may be preferable since the context of `this` will align too if it is used in the `equip` method